# Schema's schema

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Is there a [schema's](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) schema?

Maybe in [Thing > Intangible > StructuredValue](http://schema.org/StructuredValue) but can't find it in here...

The purpose would be to describe a schema.

Anyone aware of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema.org doesn't provide a way of describing schemas, but [RDF Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) (RDFS) does. See http://schema.rdfs.org/ for an expression of the Schema.org terms in RDFS. The [Turtle version](http://schema.rdfs.org/all.ttl) is probably the most readable one, but there's JSON, CSV and so on too.